# VS2008 app_offline.htm not removed after build

Tags: visual-studio-2008, build, app-offline.htm

This happens about 50% of the time I build my web application. I have it running on my localhost (start without debugging) and when I make changes and build it will always build successfully, but sometimes not remove the `app_offline.htm` file it adds for the build. I then have to either refresh the solution explorer to show the `app_offline.htm` file and delete it, or build again and it usually will rid itself of the file after that.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a solution? I'd even be happy if there were a way I could get VS to stop generating the file all together! It's not like I need to be told the app is offline when I'm the only one who can view it!